# VBA wrapping method with optional parameters

Tags: vba, wrapper

Note sure if 'wrapping' is the right terminology. Essentially, I'm building a class that has another class as a private member, and I want to expose some (not all) of the child class's functions in the parent's interface. To make the example simple, I'll use a `Collection` as an example:

```
'MyClass
Private m_ClsMyCollection As Collection

...

'Expose Collection.Count
Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = m_ClsMyCollection.Count
End Sub
```

Simple enough, but I'm hitting a bit of a sticking point when exposing methods with optional parameters. For example, `Collection.Add` is declared as

```
Collection.Add(Item, [Key], [Before], [After])
```

I'm not sure how to wrap this. Is it safe to simply do:

```
Public Sub Add(Item, Optional Key, Optional Before, Optional After)
    m_ClsMyCollection.Add Item, Key, Before, After
End Sub
```

Presumably if the optional parameters are missing, it will pass `Nothing` to those parameters in `m_ClsMyCollection.Add`, but I suspect that passing `Nothing` is not equivilent to not passing an argument at all.

The alternative seems to be to check `IsMissing` on each arg and write a pass for *every possible combination of arguments*, which seems mad:

```
Public Sub Add(Item, Optional Key, Optional Before, Optional After)
    If IsMissing(Key) And IsMissing(Before) And IsMissing(After) Then
        m_ClsMyCollection.Add Item:=Item
    ElseIf IsMissing(Key) And IsMissing(Before) Then
        m_ClsMyCollection.Add Item:=Item, After:=After
    ElseIf IsMissing(Key) And IsMissing(After) Then
        m_ClsMyCollection.Add Item:=Item, Before:=Before
    ...
End Sub
```

The amount of combinations increases exponentially with the number of optional args - even with just 3, I need to check 8 cases! Is this necessary? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to test this by doing the following:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Wrapper
End Sub

Public Sub Wrapper(Optional MyArg)
    Wrapped MyArg
End Sub

Public Sub Wrapped(Optional MyArg)
    Debug.Print IsMissing(MyArg)
End Sub
```

This outputs `True`, proving it's **not necessary to check if every optional argument is passed** - in the case above, `m_ClsMyCollection.Add Item, Key, Before, After` is sufficient regardless of which arguments were passed.

Comment: For completeness:

What happens in [Kai's example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24822453/3198973) is when `Wrapper` calls `Wrapped MyArg`, `MyArg` has a value of `Missing`. So, even though it is actually passed  to `Wrapped`, it has a value of `Missing` so, `IsMissing` evaluates to true. (Making this a completely safe thing to do.)